# About django translation template {% trans “something” %} in different systems

Tags: django

I know, I'm asking about something similar, requested a lot of times. But with a different point of view.

I'm working on a little django project. After developed the base functionalities, now I'm fighting with the multilanguage.

I was able to use a simple test template in my windows laptop. But when I copy this project to the test (CentOS) server it doesn't work.

Hereafter what I did.

The base environment (both systems) is virtualenv with python 2.7, django 1.5, mysql-python 1.2.3 and django-localeURL 1.5. gettext v.1.7.

These are the relevant options of settings.py (Note: I use django-localeURL application)

```
# Django settings for contact_site project.
import os.path
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__) # this is not Django setting.
# ... skip
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it'
#...skip
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
#...skip

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

    # LocaleMiddleware after SessionMiddleware: it needs sessions
    # commented out LocaleMiddleware to avoid conflict with LocaleURLMiddleware
    # 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',

    # LocaleURLMiddleware to manage multi language urls
    'localeurl.middleware.LocaleURLMiddleware',

    # CommonMiddleware after LocaleURLMiddleware or will not work APPEND_SLASH
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

# ... skip

_ = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _(u'English')),
    ('it', _(u'Italiano')),
    ('fr', _(u'Francais')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    # in windows laptop
    'C:/...skip.../virtualenvs/djprj/contact_site/locale',
    # in centos staging server
    # '/var/www/html/virtualenvs/djprj/contact_site/locale',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
# ...skip
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates"),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # localeurl to manage multi language urls. it must be the 1st one!
    'localeurl',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# ... skip
    # my application
    'contact',
)
# ... skip
```

my project urls.py (the home only):

```
# ... skip
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'contact_site.views.home', name='home'),
    )
```

my views.py (the home only):

```
#... skip    
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'minimalistic.html', {})
```

and finally my minimalistic template:

```
{% load debug_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
{# {% set_trace %} #}
<p>{% trans "Hello" %}</p>
<p>{% blocktrans %}Hello guys{% endblocktrans %}</p>

lingua richiesta: {{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }}
</body>
</html>
```

Then I produced the dictionaries of messages using

```
django-admin.py makemessages --all
```

I edited the dictionaries (using poedit)
and finally, running development server, in windows I saw the coveted result:

peeking from browser `http://127.0.0.1:8000/it` gave me Salve...

while getting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en` gave me Hello ...

Unfortunatly in the stage system I got Hello ... from both URLs.

Just to be safe, in centos I tried even

```
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

this operation was ok, but without different results about the minimalistic.html template rendering

And last, yes, I cleared my browser cache between tests.

Any suggestion about what am I missing? How can I debug this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm sorry and a little embarassed.

Today, debugging `django/utils/translate/trans_real.py`, I have realized the presence of a subtle typo mistake in the staging server `settings.py` file.

I cannot count how many times yesterday I checked that configuration file, missing the point!

Sorry again